# Normal Distribution of AUROCs

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have been executing multiple runs of cross-validation and obtaining several AUROCs (area under the ROC). I have found out that the distribution of those AUC follow a normal distribution. Is there any scientific explanation to that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A normal distribution of AUROC values is not possible.

Because normal distributions are infinite, but AURUC is bounded to [0:1]. So at most it looks vaguely like a normal distribution.

It's more likely that you are observing a **Binomial distribution**.

There is a probabilistic interpretation of AUROC (sorry, I don't remember the source for this). Assuming that there were a "true" probability p, and you are observing k random samples from this true probability p, the distribution of AUROC values maybe is B(n,p)/n then?

Comment: AUCROC is bound to the range [0-1] as you describe. The binomial distribution has support on positive integers. Do you perhaps mean the Beta distribution? Or can you clarify?

Comment: B(n;p) / n should be [0;1]

Comment: Turns out there are some very good papers about it: 'Comparison of non-parametric confidence intervals
for the area under the ROC curve of a
continuous-scale diagnostic test' , 'Confidence Intervals for the Area under the
ROC Curve'

Answer (score 0):

The Central Limit Theorem is often used to justify approximate normality of (sample) distributions of statistics calculated on large amounts of data. This will obviously break down for AUC close to 0 or 1 because the normal distribution has support on the entire real line.

Why do you care? Is it just for curiosity or are you trying to do something with this intuition?

If you want to compute intervals, a better technique is to use the bootstrap. If you're comparing ROCs of two models, you can bootstrap the paired decisions of the two models to get intervals on the difference.

Comment: The Central Limit Theorem actually makes quite sense. I did check some of the possible techniques for computing the confidence intervals and turns out that some make the assumption that for a high number of AUCs, the approaching distribution becomes a normal distribution, but of course with the limitation that no negative values can occure, but by using the same properties at the same time.